# Android Search specific item in Listview

Tags: android, uisearchbar

i have implemented a search bar in my listview,but now how can show my result?i get the values from a xml file(hosted on my server) there is a way to search in this file and show the results?My idea is a search from first letter

Answer (score 0):

useful,but my xml file is frequently upgraded i can't use this method,i need that while typing my listview show the result(just like your example,but with action bar)
this is the script:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute();
    }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            //Disable dismiss ultil load end
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            // Retrieve nodes from the given URL address
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://192.172.11.18/prova/xmlparseimgtxt.xml");
            // Retrive DOM element
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

            try {
                // Identify the element tag name
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("my_elements");
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(zeroElement, parser.getValue(e, zeroElement));
                    map.put(firstElement, parser.getValue(e, firstElement));
                    map.put(secondElement, parser.getValue(e, secondElement));
                    map.put(thirdElement, parser.getValue(e, thirdElement));
                    map.put(fourthElement, parser.getValue(e, fourthElement));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    arraylist.add(map);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```